# Set that a cell always has the same value as another (actively)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a macro that inserts a row on one sheet and then inserts this row in all the sheets but the separate columns should refer to the value of the general sheet.

E.g.:
I have 3 sheets and a template sheet.
Then I want to run a macro that inserts a row in the template sheet with some values.
And loops through all 3 sheets inserts the row in the same spot, and then comes the difficult part, it gives an active link to the template sheet cells.

So that when somebody changes the value of one of the cells on the template this value gets changed on all the different tabs.

I have this but this is not an active link it only sets the status of the value from that time and I can't find the syntax to make it an active reference.

```
For Each Current In Worksheets
    Current.Cells(startCell.Row, startCell.Column).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
    Current.Cells(rowNumber + 1, 1).Value = ws.Cells(rowNumber + 1, 1).Value
    Current.Cells(rowNumber + 1, 2).Value = ws.Cells(rowNumber + 1, 2).Value
    Current.Cells(rowNumber + 1, 2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Current.Cells(rowNumber + 1, 3).Value = ws.Cells(rowNumber + 1, 3).Value
    Current.Cells(rowNumber + 1, 3).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Current.Cells(rowNumber + 1, 4).Value = ws.Cells(rowNumber + 1, 4).Value
    Current.Cells(rowNumber + 1, 4).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Current.Cells(rowNumber + 1, 5).Value = ws.Cells(rowNumber + 1, 5).Value
    Current.Cells(rowNumber + 1, 5).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
Next Current
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing I was looking for was this:

```
    'First get the address you need from that cell
    testString = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, 2)).Address 
    'Add the = in front of the address
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "=" & testString
```

But I had trouble wording what I needed and the solution I've provided works but is not nice coded.
If somebody has a better solution please be so kind...